# ¿Cómo contar registros no secuenciales SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito obtener la cantidad de veces que una operación a refinanciado. Mi problema es que tengo que ir al campo operacion_hijo para obtener la operación origen y nuevamente buscarla en el campo operacion y así sucesivamente hasta validar que la operación es de tipo 20066 y que ya no tiene más operaciones hijos.

Por ejemplo, la ultima operación refinanciada es 62 (será un valor que voy a recibir de otro lado), la penúltima fue 61 y la operación que origino la refinanciación es 57, esto indica que el cliente refinanció 2 veces. Operación normal (20066), operación refinanciada (21045). Pensé usar rank() over (partition) y luego hacer un count() pero no siempre las operaciones son consecutivas con el caso de la operación 28.

Podría obtener lo que requiero mediante select? sin usar cursores.

Adjunto imagen de la tabla

[image: Imagen]

Quizás el titulo no es correcto, disculpen, es la primera vez que realizo una consulta por este medio.

Gracias.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. De la pregunta se obtiene la idea de que sabes perfectamente la dificultad de programar en Sql, por tanto y para que cada uno de los que te quiera responder no tenga que hacer todo el trabajo dale a [edit](/edit) para modificarla, e incluir el código en texto necesario para montar el escenario. También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Comment: Hola @Javifer2, gracias por el tiempo invertido y tomaré tu consejo de aquí en adelante. Es la primera vez que uso stack overflow, me seguiré informando de como se debe usar correctamente esta herramienta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por supuesto que es posible, solamente necesitas hacer uso de una CTE recursiva, en donde irá buscando los descendientes del padre y para obtener cuantas veces tuvo que descender puedes usar los niveles o hacer un count si en dado caso tus registros no tendrán hermanos, por cierto como sugerencia si es posible modifica para que en lugar de guardar en los id's de los hijos lo correcto debería ser guardar el id del padre en cada row, pero bueno dejando este tema de lado, te agrego el código con el cual puedes probar el funcionamiento de la CTE:

```
CREATE TABLE Operaciones  
(  
OperacionID SMALLINT NOT NULL, 
Descripcion NVARCHAR(64) NULL,
OperacionHijaID INT NULL
);  

INSERT INTO Operaciones VALUES 
(276, N'Operación Papá', 275)
,(275, N'Otra Operación 1', 274)  
,(274, N'Otra Operación 2', 273)  
,(273, N'Otra Operación 3', 1)
,(500, N'Otra Operación 4', 501)
,(501, N'Otra Operación Hija', null)
,(1, 'Última Operación Hija',NULL) ;  

WITH ReporteFinal(OperacionHijaID, OperacionID, Descripcion, Nivel) AS   
(  
    SELECT OperacionHijaID, OperacionID, Descripcion, 0 AS Nivel  
    FROM Operaciones   
    WHERE OperacionHijaID IS NOT NULL AND OperacionID = 276 -- Condición Inicial  
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT e.OperacionHijaID, e.OperacionID, e.Descripcion, Nivel + 1  
    FROM Operaciones AS e  
        INNER JOIN ReporteFinal AS d  
        ON e.OperacionID = d.OperacionHijaID   
)  
SELECT OperacionID, Descripcion, OperacionHijaID, Nivel   
FROM ReporteFinal RF
ORDER BY RF.Nivel
```

Este es un código que escribí de forma rápida, pero funciona, te agrego el link para que lo corrobores: [Probar código online](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d75df/10)

```
| OperacionID |           Descripcion | OperacionHijaID | Nivel |
|-------------|-----------------------|-----------------|-------|
|         276 |        Operación Papá |             275 |     0 |
|         275 |      Otra Operación 1 |             274 |     1 |
|         274 |      Otra Operación 2 |             273 |     2 |
|         273 |      Otra Operación 3 |               1 |     3 |
|           1 | Última Operación Hija |          (null) |     4 |
```

Adicionalmente te sugeriría agregarlo como una función a SQL para que reciba como parámetro el IdPadre a buscar y pueda ser más expandible y reutilizable tu aplicación. Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias @Diego, es lo que estaba necesitando. Tomare tu recomendación para incluir una función que reciba el parámetro.